# How do I push my text within linearlayout below the progress bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a frame layout containing a linearlayout which has progressbar on the left and text on the right. I am trying to push to textview below the progress bar, and I tried layout_below, but it doesnt work within the elements of linearlayout.How do I push the text exactly below the progress bar? any clue? Here's my xml file for the same:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loading_spinner" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loading_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/no_result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/no_result"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:orientation="vertical"` to LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="gone" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loading_spinner" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loading_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
```